# Vue - getting data attribute value in css

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, styles, custom-data-attribute

Is there any option to get data attribute value in Vue css?

```
<template>
   <p data-background="purple"> TEST </p>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
p {
  background: attr(data-background); //error
  &:after {
     background: attr(data-background); //error
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) for this case.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    elStyle: {
      '--background': 'lightblue',
    }
  }
});
```

```css
p:after {
  content: 'A pseudo element';
  background: var(--background, red); // Red is the fallback value
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p :style="elStyle"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't set background in :before and :after pseudo selectors.

Comment: If you need to style pseudo elements, you can handle that with `CSS custom properties`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately I need to support IE11.